# Textblock margin causes out of bounds text

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, marquee

I'm currently trying to create a visual component to have scrolling text (left to right and right to left) - pretty much an html marquee.

I have a grid divided in several columns & rows, and I want to place my component inside one of the grid slots.

The grid (named UIGrid) is generated like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < xDivisions; i++)
{
    ColumnDefinition newColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
    UIGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(newColumn);
}
for (int i = 0; i < yDivisions; i++)
{
    RowDefinition newRow = new RowDefinition();
    UIGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(newRow);
}
```

The component I'm adding is just a border with a textblock as a child. I place the border inside the Grid like this :

```
border = new Border();
Grid.SetColumn(border, xPosition);
Grid.SetRow(border, yPosition);

textBlock = new TextBlock();
border.Child = textBlock;
textBlock.Text = "Scrolling text from left to right";

UIGrid.Children.Add(border);
```

I'm using a timer to increment the textblock margin, here's the timer callback simplified body :

```
textBlock.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
double textWidth = textBlock.DesiredSize.Width;
double visibleWidth = componentBase.ActualWidth;
double targetMargin = textWidth < visibleWidth ? visibleWidth : textWidth;

if (margin.Left == targetMargin)
{
    margin.Left = -textWidth;
} else
{
    margin.Left++;
}
```

When the text slides from left to right, it behaves nicely :
https://s10.postimg.org/p0nt7vl09/text_good.png
Text "leaving" the grid slot is hidden.

However, when I set the textblock's margin as negative so it may come back inside the viewable area from the left, the text is visible even though it's outside its allocated slot :
https://s10.postimg.org/pownqtjq1/text_bad.png

I've tried using padding instead, but I can't set a negative padding. I've tried a few other things, but I feel like I've encountered a roadblock.

What could I do to get a nicely scrolling text ?

Comment: It would be nice if you post the grid xaml so that we can see what exactly is going on. for now try setting the Textblock horizontal Alignment inside Grid to Stretch

Comment: @AVKNaidu Changing the horizontal alignment of either the Textblock or the Border didn't change the scrolling behavior =(

Comment: I'd love to know why you people are so paranoid about sharing code or saying clearly what your actual problem is. Anyway, find your outermost control (I think it might be a Grid) and set `ClipToBounds="True"` on it. That may solve at least part of your problem, though it's hard to be sure since you're so secretive.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Oh it's not really being secretive, I just don't want to dump all of my code and say "here, debug this please". I admit I could have showed more code here, minus points for me. As for 'ClipToBounds', it seems there is no such property in UWP, only a 'Clip' property that is a rectangle I have to set myself. I'm still fighting with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ed Plunkett led me in the right direction with the Clip property. The idea is to do this :

```
border.Clip = new RectangleGeometry
{
    Rect = new Rect(0, 0, border.ActualWidth, border.ActualHeight)
};
```

Of course, that doesn't work if the border hasn't been rendered yet (and of course it isn't when my code is running). You can force the measurement to take place using 'Measure' as I did to measure the text length in pixels, but it behaved strangely on my border. I wouldn't get the correct size at all.

In the end, I simply subscribed to the border's SizeChanged event :

```
border.SizeChanged += OnSizeComputed;
```

When that event is fired, I create the RectangleGeometry using ActualWidth & ActualHeight.

Answer (score 0):

If you want nicely scrolling text ListView might be a better option. It is dynamic and you can bind it to your object. It would take a lot of this guess work out.